# Google Chrome weird font rendering

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webfonts, google-webfonts

My first post and my first question :)

I have weird Google font rendering issue that I don't know how to solve. It happens totally randomly when I refresh page. 80% of text is 'Lato' and the rest of it is Times new roman, everything is one H element.

From devtools:

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/964622/34faab37f4da6f3ce33ca56445a2a414

Once I change something in CSS font is back to normal. I have tried to activate repaint/re-flow of layout and nothing happens.

Here is [a link](http://demo.mekshq.com/herald/)

Try to browse demo site and see what is happening with trending posts font

Comment: When I browse your site, the last word sometimes is rendered in Times, that's true. But after a second, it becomes Lato. So, the reason may be in the "weight" of the site itself - it just too slowly rendered to a user. If it soleves yur problem, I will repost it as answer.

Comment: Problem is solved with adding  text-rendering:auto; CSS declaration. Apparently  text-rendering:optimizeLegibility; has some bug with Google Webfonts in new version of Chrome.

Comment: I had a similar issue, setting text-rendering to auto fixed it. Thanks!